# Build gradle failed but on another project

Tags: android-studio, gradle, module

I'm starting to use Android Studio instead of Eclipse.
I'm trying to import Modules from Eclipse workspace and after a change in some versions of Build Tools, Clean, Rebuild and Sync project with gradle files, it works!

But now it's happening something very very weird: on a project with some modules imported from Eclipse, when I Rebuild project, Gradle failed with one error:

"Gradle sync failed: The SDK Build Tools revision (18.1.0) is too low for project ':smmiet'. Minimum required is 19.1.0
        Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)"

The fact is that this "smmiet" project is a module ON ANOTHER PROJECT!!!
So this module doesn't belong to the project that I'm building.

How comes in your opinion?

Thanks.[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oU5lf.png)

Comment: post your build.gradle.!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, it has been a stupid error... a drag and drop has moved one module away, without my control.